# How do I copy and filter a DAO recordset in VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, dao, recordset

Due to problems with DAO (see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100372/undefined-function-when-using-dao-querydef-in-vba)), I need to create an Excel VBA Recordset from an Access query and filter its results using a user-defined function.

I thought I could use the following code to accomplish this:

```
Sub test()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rs_clone As Recordset

Set db = OpenDatabase(dbPath)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select testVal from dataTable")
Set rs_clone = rs.Clone
rs_clone.MoveLast
rs_clone.MoveFirst
while not rs_clone.eof
 if myUDF(rs_clone!testVal) then
    rs_clone.delete
 end if
 rs_clone.moveNext
wend

End Sub
```

But that actually deletes values from my source table, so the clone isn't a new recordset that I can freely alter, it's just another pointer to the original one.  How can I use my UDF to filter out the records I don't want, while leaving the original data untouched, if putting the UDF in the query itself is not an option?

Comment: 17 questions, only 3 upvotes cast.

Comment: @Mitch, when is it appropriate to upvote?  If I select an answer does that accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Recordsets have a filter property, so you can create a new recordset that is a filtered version of an existing recordset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .getrows method:

```
Dim rs_clone As Variant

...

rs_clone = rs.getrows(numrows)
```

then process the resulting 2-d array.

Answer (score 2):

In Access with DAO, this is how you'd do it:

```
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rsFiltered As DAO.Recordset

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblInventory.* FROM tblInventory;")
  rs.MoveLast
  Debug.Print "Unfiltered: " & rs.RecordCount

  rs.filter = "[LastUpdated]>=#1/1/2011#"
  Set rsFiltered = rs.OpenRecordset
  rsFiltered.MoveLast
  Debug.Print "Filtered: " & rsFiltered.RecordCount

  rsFiltered.Close
  Set rsFiltered = Nothing
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
```

However, note that (as mentioned in the help file), it may be just as fast to simply reopen the recordset with new criteria, instead of filtering the existing recordset.

Comment: Interesting; I didn't know about the .Filter property.  I'll have to check this out and see if it's faster than what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()
Sub Export_Click()

Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, sql As String, r As Variant

Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim excelWbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim excelSht As Object
Dim rng As Excel.Range

Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
On Error Resume Next
Set excelWbk = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("Folder Name(Template)")

Set db = CurrentDb()
sql1 = "Select * from Query_New"
sql2 = "Select * from Query_Expired"
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(sql1, dbReadOnly)
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(sql2, dbReadOnly)

Dim SheetName1 As String
Dim SheetName2 As String

SheetName1 = "New"
SheetName2 = "Expired"

'For first sheet
On Error Resume Next
excelWbk.Sheets(SheetName1).Select

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox Err.Number
excelWbk.Close False
appExcel.Quit
Exit Sub
End If

With excelWbk.Activesheet
    .Cells(5, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs1
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'For second sheet
On Error Resume Next
excelWbk.Sheets(SheetName2).Select

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox Err.Number
excelWbk.Close False
appExcel.Quit
Exit Sub
End If

With excelWbk.Activesheet
    .Cells(5, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs2
    On Error GoTo 0
End With


rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
rs2.Close
Set rs2 = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing

On Error Resume Next

excelWbk.SaveAs "C:\Documents and settings\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\Decision.xlsx"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox Err.Number
End If

excelWbk.Close False
appExcel.Quit
Set appExcel = Nothing
MsgBox "The report has been saved"
End Sub




End Sub
```